# Prevent changes to an object on one window affecting another

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, dapper

On my main window I have a datagrid which loads a List of objects from SQL:

```
if (PartView.Instance.CurrentPart != null)
{
    DgSupplierData.ItemsSource = partData.GetAllPartSuppliersByPart(PartView.Instance.CurrentPart.Id);
}
```

partData is just a helper class which uses dapper to load a list from stored procedures.

When the user double clicks a row an "edit window" is opened, a basic window which assigns the row data to a custom object (PartSupplierModel) for the user to edit. Once they edit the data and hit the save button, a stored procedure will save the data to SQL Server (pretty straight forward and works just fine). However, if the user makes any changes to any of the textboxes, but then decides they do not wish to save the changes and they just close the form then reselects the same row, the form will keep the changes they made (although will not save to SQL Server as the button event was not called, which is what we want). What I want is for the data to not change the source in the original table unless the edit/save button has been clicked. I believe this is due to the way that I have binded the object? However, being new to WPF I am struggling to understand how to prevent this functionality.

Example: This shows how I have setup the textboxes on the edit form

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtManufacturer"
                     Text="{Binding Manufacturer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Height="25"
                     MaxLength="150"/>
```

The object is stored as a member variable upon the edit form being loaded, and set to being the datacontext:

```
private PartSupplierModel _partSupplier = new PartSupplierModel();

public PartSupplierView(PartSupplierModel supplierData = null, int partId = 0)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _partSupplier = supplierData;

            this.DataContext = _partSupplier;
        }
```

Comment: public PartSupplierView() is a constructor of a form which is called only once when "new" is used.  If you create a Load() method and put the line : this.DataContext = _partSupplier; then every time you use the Show() method the DGV will be load with original data.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough info to effectively answer this but I hope it'll give some pointers:

```
    private PartSupplierModel _partSupplier = new PartSupplierModel();

    public PartSupplierView(PartSupplierModel supplierData = null, int partId = 0)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _partSupplier = supplierData;

        this.DataContext = _partSupplier;
    }
```

There's no* point saying `_partSupplier = new ...` because the only thing you do in the constructor is overwrite this with a passed-in variable, `supplierData`

Doing that doesn't perform any kind of clone or copy, it just means you have some object in memory somewhere and you point the form at it

The user makes edits, the original object in memory is altered, the form is closed but the o next remains altered. If you open a new form it doesn't matter that it's new, it is pointed to the original altered object in memory

You might as well write:

```
    public PartSupplierView(PartSupplierModel supplierData = null, int partId = 0)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = supplierData;
    }
```

Does this help you understand, that if you never do something that cancels the changes true user makes, or if you never refresh the object passed in as `supplierData`, then each time this form opens it will be looking at the ever evolving, altered object

There are many ways to solve this problem but usually they boil down to:

- work on a copy and throw it away if the user cancels or merge its data into the "main" object or save it to the db if they don't (the db is the main object)
- build a facility into the data model that it tracks original and changed values and revert the changes values back to the original values if the user cancels (each property is backed by two fields original/current. When first created both fields are written to but thereafter only current is updated. Two methods that accept/reject changes are used to copy original to current (reject) or current to original (accept) depending on what you want to do. Data containers like DataTable/DataRow do this
- refresh the object from the db if the user clicks cancel - this is broadly the same as "working on a copy", in that the db is the source of truth and the local object is very temporary. This way makes heavier use of the db

We can't really be concrete as to what to do because your question doesn't give any info about where `supplierData` comes from, how it's stored, what it's expected lifecycle is etc.. That's what you need to decide; this form is editing that object so how to you want to handle reverting the changes? Get the object again/restore it from a local copy of itself or internally track and be able to undo? There isn't a right/wrong answer to that- it depends on the concurrency and performance requirements of the system

*<sub>unless it helps avoid something crash for nullref reasons in InitializeComponent, but this is ancillary to my point that making a new one of it is useless because all you do is throw the new away and edit the original data</sub>